# Why i can not delete folder with du?

Tags: sorting, head, rm, du

I can't understand how to delete several folder by size with 'du'

sudo du -h --apparent-size /folder-to-delete/*.* | sort -h | head -n 65 | sudo rm -rf

Thanks for helpful ;)

Comment: Look up `xargs`

Comment: BTW doing `sudo` stuff is not a good idea

Comment: Do you have more example?

Comment: @EdHeal I just try with this :  sudo du -h --apparent-size /folder-to-delete/*.* | sort -h | head -n 65 | sudo xargs rm     - rm: cannot remove '/folder-to-delete/’: No such file or directory